# Nsurl return nil when i am selecting iPhone language except English

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, encoding, nsurl

i m calling default map app. from my application but for example when i select Portugal language on my iphone for current location NSURL return nil.
I already used UTF8encoding and percentage encapsulate as follows:-

```
 NSString *encodedURLString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //where urlString has value http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Localiza\u00e7\u00e3o+actual&daddr=28.6522907,77.1929857
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

i already try NSUTF8Encoding instead NSASCIIStringEncoding but nothing helped.
thanx for any help.

Comment: Did you try printing out the value of the string after encoding it but before creating a URL from it? Its odd to encode the whole URL string, normally you would just encode the request data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are percent-encoding the entire URL.

This turns `http://www.google.com` into `http%3A//www.google.com`, which is a malformed URL.

From the NSURL Class Reference:

> **Return Value:** An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the string was malformed, returns nil.

Ergo, you are receiving nil.

What you want to do is this:

```
NSString *path = @"http://maps.google.com/maps";
NSString *query = @"saddr=Localiza\u00e7\u00e3o+actual&daddr=28.6522907,77.1929857";
query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?%@", path, query];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: url];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: URL];
```